# Caractéristiques linguistiques du français en linguistique comparée

Tags: linguistique, comparaison-de-langues

Ma question s'adresse soit aux linguistes, soit à des personnes qui ont une bonne connaissance de la linguistique en général et de la linguistique comparée.

Mon grand-père me disait souvent que si le français était resté aussi longtemps la langue des traités, la langue de la diplomatie, (et elle l'est encore dans une certaine mesure), et la langue de philo, c'est parce qu'il y avait une raison.

C'est une langue précise.

Je voudrais savoir en quoi le français se distingue linguistiquement, et en fait sa précision.

Si ce n'est pas votre opinion, et que vous ne pensez pas que c'est une langue spécialement précise, du moins, quelles particularités linguistiques font que le français est un langue qui est avantageuse à utiliser pour les traités ou la philo?

Edit: Encore une fois, je ne demande pas si pour vous cette affirmation est vraie ou fausse, je demande sur quoi cette réputation de langue précise s'est bâtie. Je ne pense pas qu'une réputation puisse se bâtir entièrement sur du vent, donc, il doit y avoir linguistiquement des raisons. Je rechercherai des articles en langues étrangères parlant de la précision du français.

https://www.achyra.org/francais/viewtopic.php?t=4640

Comment: La question serait mieux sur [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) ou [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/). La question part, à mon avis, sur un faux prémisse,  le français n'a pas été (passé, elle ne l'est plus depuis 100 ans) la langue prédominante de la diplomatie parce que « c'est une langue précise » mais parce qu'elle a remplacé le latin quand celui-ci a décliné et son rayonnement est dû à des raisons culturelles, on parlait français dans la plupart des cours d'Europe, ce qui en fit la langue de la diplomatie.

Comment: On me demanderait quelle est la langue de la philosophie, je dirais l'allemand, mais avant de l'affirmer je demanderais sur [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/). À lire : [Le français, langue de la diplomatie?](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/idees/478351/le-francais-langue-de-la-diplomatie), et aussi [l'interview de la philologue et philosophe Babara Cassin](https://www.lepoint.fr/dossiers/hors-series/grandes-expressions-philosophiques/barbara-cassin-les-philosophes-touchent-a-la-langue-autant-qu-a-la-verite-14-11-2017-2172377_3484.php), entre autres !

Comment: Effectivement, je devrais poser la question sur "Linguistique. Il y a des tonnes de livres anciens qui parlent de la précision du français et beaucoup sont en langues étrangères. On en parle même dans les couloirs des diplomates. Le français a la réputation d'être une langue précise, c'est un fait. Je demande pourquoi a-t-elle cette réputation. Je suis polyglotte, et effectivement, j'ai remarqué que le français était particulièrement précis car pointilleux sur la grammaire.

Comment: La personne qui a voté pour "opinion based", n'a pas compris la question.

Comment: Et tu ne te demandes même pas si la question est bien rédigée ? Dire que le français est la langue de la diplomatie parce qu'elle est « précise » part d'une opinion personnelle (fausse comme je l'ai déjà dit, et là on peut trouver des références historiques et non linguistiques)  et ne peut engendrer que des réponses biaisées.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une opinion personnelle. Peut-être que ma réponse est mal rédigée effectivement ("tu ne te demandes même pas?" est une façon un peu agressive de me le dire), mais la question constate "beaucoup de gens ont dit que le français est une langue précise, etc" (pour le "beaucoup de gens", des auteurs, des diplomates, et des bruits de couloir aussi (=réputation) donc sur quoi pourrait se baser cette réputation. Je constate une opinion, je demande sur quoi elle se peut se baser linguistiquement. Ai-je dit que c'était la mienne?

Comment: La référence ajoutée dans la question n'a aucune caution scientifique, c'est aussi une affirmation gratuite suivie d'une vague discussion qui n'apporte pas à mon avis de réponse, si je n'ai pas vu la réponse scientifique, alors merci de faire le lien vers cette réponse et pas vers ce forum.

Comment: Il aurait peut-être fallu éviter de dire que je n'avais pas compris la question. Et je répète « "beaucoup de gens ont dit que le français est une langue précise, etc" (pour le "beaucoup de gens", des auteurs, des diplomates, et des bruits de couloir aussi (=réputation) donc sur quoi pourrait se baser cette réputation. » doit être accompagné de citations ou références précises puisque tu les admets comme « vrais ».

Comment: Si j'avais posé la question je serais partie d'une explication de texte de ce [discours d'un membre de l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/fidele-sa-mission-diplomatique-la-langue-francaise-continue) qui reprend beaucoup de poncifs. Avec une attention toute particulière aux mots « élites » (que j'aurais préféré dans la réponse de @Circeus) « l’histoire, la culture des lettres, l’intérêt général », « admirable logique de notre langage ». « Précise, élégante et claire, notre langue devient naturellement le véhicule de la pensée au sein d’une Europe spirituellement unie. »

Comment: Comme « langue précise » n'est pas expliqué dans la question (et aurait dû l'être) j'ai cherché ce que ça pouvait vouloir dire et le mieux que j'ai trouvé est ceci [Précision, prévenance, coprésence : les singularités de la langue française](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/nos-coups-de-coeur/caracteristiques-singularites-atouts-langue-francaise/) qui peut éventuellement donner un argument linguistique à « précis », mais bien sûr ça ne cautionne pas que le français ait été la langue de la diplomatie, rien à voir à mon avis.

Comment: Et un avis différent. [La supposée précision du français](http://david.monniaux.free.fr/dotclear/index.php/post/2013/06/04/La-suppos%C3%A9e-pr%C3%A9cision-du-fran%C3%A7ais). Finalement c'est peut-être sur [skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) que la question devrait être posée !

Comment: Ben voilà, que l'avis soit différent ou identique, c'est discuter linguistiquement de ce fait qui m'intéresse. Vous êtes en plein dans ma question, contrairement à toutes les réponses données. Ce qui m'intéresse ce sont les arguments "pour" ou "contre", mais pas données comme des avis comme la réponse faite en dessous,(qui n'est qu'un avis), mais faire une argumentation en s'appuyant sur la linguistique, l'argumentation peut être négative ou positive, peu importe.

Comment: La réponse du bas est particulièrement mauvaise à mon avis, car elle inclut des jugements de valeur sans s'appuyer sur des sources (et je souhaite une explication) scientifique "Il n'y aucune raison linguistique que ce soit", c'est purement un avis, pas une démonstration. Elle a eu 2 upvote, mais elle est mauvaise, c'est une opinion qui répond à ce qu'elle croit être une opinion dans ma question, j'ai peut-être mal formulé ma question, mais la réponse est hors-sujet.

Comment: En plus vous trouvez plein de références à cette "précision" donc je n'ai pas rêvé, et pondu cette hypothèse, c'est bien ce que je disais. Grosse contradiction ici.

Comment: Aucune contradiction, vous ne donnez que des opinions qui restent vagues (ce qui n'est de mise ici, voir le Help Centre), qui ne reposent sur aucune citation(s), vous n'expliquez pas « précis » j'ai donc cherché ce que voulez dire et **j'ai eu confirmation**, en citant deux articles (relativement sérieux et pas n'importe quel forum) que le mot précis ne relève que de l'opinion et rien ne contredit ce que j'ai dit : je ne suis pas d'accord quand vous dites : « si le français était resté aussi longtemps la langue des traités, la langue de la diplomatie, c'est parce qu'il y avait une raison. »

Comment: Et lisez le Code of Conduct des sites de SE.

Comment: À propos de [votre commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/caract%c3%a9ristiques-linguistiques-du-fran%c3%a7ais-en-linguistique-compar%c3%a9e?noredirect=1#comment80368_40140) c'était à vous de donner de donner ces citations pour appuyer votre présupposé de départ. Rappel :  [avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

Il n'y **aucune raison linguistique** que ce soit. Prétendre le contraire tient du pur chauvinisme.

La seule raison, c'est que le français est devenue la langue de l'aristocratie européenne au cours du 18e siècle (un peu au même titre que le Grec était la langue des Romains cultivés), et son maintien subséquent n'est rien de plus que que de l'inertie culturelle des plus classiques.

Personnellement (**théorie entièrement personnelle!**), je crois que le courant Précieux, vers la fin du 17e siècle, et son approche plutôt élitiste, voire carrément classiste, on rendu le français très attirant aux yeux des aristocrate et de la royauté du reste de l'Europe, et même au-delà (le français était aussi parlé à la cours d'Égypte).

Comment: Non, rien à voir avec le chauvinisme, car c'est une opinion qui a été maintes fois formulée par des non français.

Comment: @Quidam Si l'opinion que le français est la langue de la diplomatie  parce que une langue précise « a été maintes fois formulée » merci d'inclure des **citations** à l'appui de la question. Je suis d'accord que le mot chauvinisme est mal choisi dans cette réponse (que je n'ai cependant pas moinssoyée) mais avec une question qui part sur de faux à priori et des opinions personnelles on ne peut pas obtenir de réponse scientifique. Et la raison historique est correcte très nombreux articles sérieux accessibles), mais FL n'est pas le bon endroit pour en discuter.

Comment: Voir le lien que j'ai inclus dans la question. J'en mettrai d'autres plus tard.

Comment: Finalement après avoir lu [ce discours](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/fidele-sa-mission-diplomatique-la-langue-francaise-continue) le mot chauvinisme ne me semble pas incongru. + 1 (même si je pense que la question telle qu'elle est posée n'a pas sa place sur FL, ce n'est pas une question assez précise, (too broad).

Comment: Prouvez-le, je ne demande que ça, c'est ma question, s'appuyer sur des faits, et débattre. Ici, cette réponse est pleine d'opinions personnelles que je n'ai pas demandées "l n'y aucune raison linguistique" et "théorie entièrement personnelle": complètement HS ! (et je l'ai bien précisé), ce qui m'intéresse n'est pas qu'on démontre que c'est vrai, mais qu'on s'appuie sur des faits linguistiques pour démontrer la validité ou l'invalidité. C'est pour ça que j'ai demandé à des gens de donner des arguments en linguistique comparée. Encore 1 fois, réponse qui ne donne aucun fait linguistique: HS

Comment: @quidam Je doute que l'on puisse trouver des études relatives à la supériorité d'une langue sur une autre, spécialement s'agissant de notions aussi subjectives que la précision ou l'affinité avec les traités car ce type d'affirmation de supériorité est plus du ressort de l'idéologie que de la linguistique.

Comment: [*L’un des traits d’idéologie linguistique, réside dans l’idée ordinaire des locuteurs, de l’inégalité de langues. Cette représentation idéologique des langues consiste à faire croire que les langues sont d’inégales valeurs. Elle provient le plus souvent de préjugés ethnocentriques, qui consistent à la dévalorisation des langues d’altérités, pour maintenir la supériorité de sa propre langue/culture et de son groupe* (Beacco, 2003)](https://arlap.hypotheses.org/3373)

Comment: Ce n'est pas à propos de la supériorité, mais d'une propriété linguistique, qui existe ou non.

Comment: Aucune raison linguistique ? Habhé ? *"Nous ne nous risquerons pas à dire que c'est faux! Ce serait en effet une affirmation tout aussi dogmatique et, en tant que telle, tout aussi indémontrable.*"

Answer (score 1):

*« alors qu’en Italie la muse converse en chantant, qu’en France elle raconte et ratiocine avec préciosité, qu’en Espagne elle a l’imagination chevaleresque, qu’en Angleterre, elle pense avec acuité et profondeur, que fait-elle en Allemagne ? Elle imite! »* (1)

On pourrait effectivement partir ainsi d'un présupposé *génie des langues*, accumuler deux ou trois clichés et aboutir immanquablement à ce que Lefebvre nomme un *nationalisme ontologique.*
C'est à la critique de ce genre d'affirmation que se sont attachés les divers intervenants dans cette question mais je crois comprendre que ce n'est pas là la préoccupation de l'OP.

---

Et cette préoccupation n'est pas absurde. Tout informaticien sait que certains langages de programmation conviennent mieux à certains types de développements que d'autres et ce même si le choix final reposera le plus souvent sur des questions de disponibilité et de compétence quand ce ne sera que de banale affinité. Pourquoi en irait-il différemment avec les langues des hommes ?
Et cette préoccupation a toute légitimité à être exposée ici. Une langue appartient plus à ceux qui la pratiquent qu'aux linguistes qui la décortiquent.

---

**Un critère comptable :**

C'est commode ça la compta... le comptage est factuel et la conclusion nécessairement objective.

**Compter les mots :** On serait évidemment bien tenté de se dire que plus une langue a de mots et plus elle offre de possibilités de s'exprimer avec précision. Au lexique le plus fourni, l'apanage de la précision.
Bon... je passe sur la difficulté qu'il y aura à se sortir du cas des synonymes (mots différents n'offrant aucune précision supplémentaire) et des homonymes (mots identiques offrant plusieurs sens différents)... pour tomber sur l'écueil qui fout tout en l'air : Comment traiter le cas de l'allemand et de sa facilité à fabriquer des mots valises ? Le célèbre *Unabhängigkeitserklärung*... y compte pour un ou pas ?

**Compter les intraduisibles :** Si, dans une traduction de Langue A vers Langue B on peut dénombrer plus de mots (ou expressions ou tournures syntaxiques ou tournures grammaticales) intraduisibles (2) que dans l'autre sens alors A pourra sans conteste et objectivement être dite plus riche que B.

À cet égard, le verdict est sans appel, sur un corpus très étendu... (incluant aussi évidemment que forcément des textes... philosophiques) :

1/ Allemand
2/ Grec ancien

3/ Les autres! Au fait... c'est quoi les autres ?

Classement confortant alors l'intuition de... Martin Heidegger (3) et de la tradition qui s'ensuivra que l'on ne peut faire de philosophie sérieuse qu'en allemand.
Mais attention! Si on peut admettre que la plus riche des langues est la plus capable de dire l'être dans tous ses états... en fait-ce pour autant la plus capable à dire le vrai ?

---

**D'ailleurs, que compte-t-on et est-on bien sûr qu'on parle tous de la même chose ?**
Quand l'Allemand écrit : *die Welt* que je vais m'empresser de traduire, moi m'sieu!, moi! facile! par : *le monde*... au fait! Est-ce bien si immédiat que cela ?
De fait, cette traduction n'est acceptable qu'à la condition expresse que le concept que l'allemand étiquette par *die Welt* soit rigoureusement identique au concept que le français étiquette par *le monde*. C'est encore à dire que :

- Soit ces concepts sont identiques à une *chose-en-soi*, sorte de recette de cuisine ou plan suivis rigoureusement par un Grand-Architecte et laissés par suite dans le domaine public...   ce qui est un à priori tout aussi dogmatique qu'idéaliste,
- Soit que ce concept fait partie des universaux, à priori dogmatique d'un autre idéalisme,
- Soit que ces mots étiquettent un phénomène dont la représentation est identique pour l'Allemand et le Français, un signifié transcendental, encore un à priori d'un encore autre idéalisme.

Et là ? Hé bhé on est mal ! Qu'est-ce qu'on comptait tout à l'heure en tant que difficultés de traduction ? Mhé! **Sauf à priori dogmatique**, TOUT, absolument TOUT est rigoureusement impossible à traduire.

Alors ? *Geist = Esprit* ? Quiconque se plonge dans la traduction réalise immédiatement que les lexiques dessinent des cartes de concepts qui ne se recouvrent pas, que les réseaux conceptuels ne se superposent pas, réalité que Schleiermacher exprime mieux que je ne le pourrais :

*« chaque langue contient […] un système de concepts qui, précisément parce qu’ils se touchent, s’unissent et se complètent dans la même langue, forment un tout dont les différentes parties ne correspondent à aucune de celles du système des autres langues, à l’exception et encore, de Dieu et de l’Être, le premier substantif et le premier verbe. Car même l’absolument universel, bien qu’il se trouve hors du domaine de la particularité, est éclairé et coloré par la langue »* (4)

Un mot ne représente qu'un point de vue, une somme d'expériences sur une chose dont la *réalité* agit au mieux en tant que principe régulateur ? Ergo... :

L'allemand est la langue la plus appropriée pour exprimer... la philosophie allemande!

Oh! Wait! Quel allemand au fait ? Pas celui de Kant hein ? Si ? Demandez donc à Heine, Nietzsche ou Schopenhauer ce qu'ils en pensent de l'allemand de Kant! (5)... Ergo :

**L'allemand-de-Heidegger est la langue la plus appropriée pour exprimer la philosophie de Heidegger!**

est la seule conclusion rationnelle à laquelle on peut aboutir.
Je réalise bien que vous avoir contraint à avaler trois pages pour balancer en conclusion une tautologie va me valoir une projection de tomates, j'espère juste que la logique que j'ai cherché à y mettre aura transformé une intuition en connaissance rationnelle.

Et puis... surtout que... en fait... je n'en ai pas encore fini... tant... suspense... suspense :

---

**Mais tout est dans tout... et réciproquement... *vorweg*!**

Stay tuned!

---

<sup>1 : Herder, Lettres sur l’avancement de l’humanité, fin XVIIIe.</sup>

<sup>2 : Par *intraduisible*, j'entends non seulement qu'il ne soit pas traduit mais aussi le fait qu'il soit traduit très différemment en chaque occurrence ou que le traducteur doive recourir à un néologisme ou à un mot existant auquel il confère un nouveau sens. Bref! Une galère à traduire quoi! Que cela finisse traduit tant mal que pas.</sup>

<sup>3 : Martin Heidegger dont la propre contribution au score des intraduisibles allemands ne compte pas vraiment pour rien!</sup>

<sup>4 : In *Des différentes méthodes du traduire* 1999.</sup>

<sup>5 : Certains le diront *Kanzleideutsch*, d'autres *glänzende Trockenheit* que pour être conséquent... je vous laisse traduire... moi... je n'ai pas compris que c'était des compliments...</sup>

Comment: "Pourquoi en irait-il différemment avec les langues des hommes ?"  Depuis un certain temps, les languages de programmation sont en général aussi d'abord destinés aux hommes. :-)

Comment: @Unfrancophone : Oui! Avec une nuance importante ici : Ils ne sont pas **conçus pour** structurer la pensée de l'homme. C'est la pensée de l'informaticien qui va structurer le développement. Alors que... et ce sera l'objet du second volet à venir... les langues des hommes structurent leur pensée... et Lycée Hoche! :-)

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord.  Ils sont conçus pour structurer et limiter la pensée des hommes à ce qui est faisable par les machines.

Comment: @Unfrancophone : Sauf que... avant de l'écrire, tu as pensé ton commentaire et j'ai pensé ma réponse en français alors que... quand l'informaticien conçoit une fonction à réaliser par la machine, il ne la pense pas dans le langage qui sera utilisé pour la programmer. C'est en ce sens que je dis que le langage informatique ne structure pas la pensée de l'homme. Après... qu'il la contingente, c'est très possible mais c'est une autre histoire.

Comment: "quand l'informaticien conçoit une fonction à réaliser par la machine, il ne la pense pas dans le langage qui sera utilisé pour la programmer" pas d'accord.  Quand je programme dans un langage familier, c'est un processus très proche de quand je parle une langue familière.  Et quand je programme dans un langage non familier, c'est souvent très proche d'une traduction d'un langage familier dans le premier.  Avec tous les effets indésirables d'une structure non idiomatique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone : Quand tu programmes la fonction oui! Pas quand tu la conçois. Quand tu traduis une opération particulière dans le langage oui! Pas quand tu décides que cette opération particulière sera nécessaire dans la réalisation de la fonction. La preuve ? Si je te demande de me coder un analyseur de spectre, je suis sûr que tu ne vas pas te popogner le codage d'une FFT! Tu vas deviner qu'une FFT est nécessaire et tu vas aller chercher une bibli dans laquelle le job est déjà fait. Quand je parle de l'informaticien et de sa pensée, je pense à l'analyse fonctionnelle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100549/discussion-between-acoswt-and-un-francophone).

Comment: Cette magnifique réponse, tout aussi hors-sujet pour FL que l'est la question, m'a fait penser à notre nouvelle académicienne, Barbara Cassin (lueur d'espoir dans ce corps figé ?) qui a souvent écrit sur le sujet et dont je renvoie à l'article accessible en ligne [*Penser en langues
Présentation du Vocabulaire Européen des philosophies*](https://journals.openedition.org/trivium/4768). Umberto Eco vient aussi à l'esprit (un autre érudit ;-)).

Comment: @Laure : Cassin ? la **co**-auteure de l'incontournable *Dictionnaire des instraduisibles* ? Oui! Absolument... ce n'est pas vraiment un hasard. Mais NON! cette question a bien toute sa place ici! N'ayant pris qu'une seule tomate... la seconde partie va arriver qui diverge de BC... quoique...